# Writing each value in dictionary to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which the keys can have multiple values. I want to create a text file for each key and write each value to it's own line in the file. How can I do this? I currently have this but this writes all values, as a list, to the first line. I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

```
    f = open(str(os.path.join(dir) + key + '.txt'),"w+")
    f.write(str(value) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Can you show the dictionary?

Comment: [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {"a": ["1", "2", "3"], "b": ["1"]}

for key, value in d.items():
  filename = str(os.path.join(dir) + key + '.txt')
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for v in value:
      f.write(v + "\n")
```

You can loop on the dictionary and create a new file for each key and start writing values on new lines.